# Sorting a generic ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have a list of points. I represented this as an ArrayList of ArrayLists. I'm trying to use generics so that the list can store Integers, Floats, etc. and treat them the same. So I have:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Number>>.
```

I need to compare these lists based on one element in each inner list.

So to do that I wrote a custom Comparator that I'm using in Collections.sort

The Comparator looks like:

```
int compare(ArrayList<? extends Number> a, ArrayList<? extends Number> b )
{
    return a.get(index).compareTo(b.get(index))
}
```

This doesn't compile of course. The compiler complains that there is no compareTo method for the wildcard class.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: How are you going to handle points with different dimensions with this structure? E.g. What if you have (1,1,1) and (2,1) and have chosen the third element to compare on?

Comment: That's actually another problem in itself. Right now I just check that all the points are of the proper dimension and throw an error otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about defining your `Comparator` class as:

```
class MyComparator<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> 
                                          implements Comparator<ArrayList<T>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<T> a, ArrayList<T> b) {
        return a.get(index).compareTo(b.get(index));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. I'm new to generics, could you tell me what the concept at work here is? Especially this: MyComparator<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>

Comment: Well `T extends Number & Comparable<T>>` implies that `T` is a `Number` *and* that it is `Comparable` - which is essentially what you want. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) is a good resource to learn about generics. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) is good for bounded type parameters.

Comment: for best results use `Comparable<? super T>`